# failed inserting a data from a table to another table with insert then select method

Tags: php

I have made a project but I have a problem when inserting data from a table to another table. 
I use insert, then do select method here.

Last time I had to use that code worked well but after I add 1 more table in my db, the code no longer works. I just add more `date` table at my db. That `date` table contains the date now(). Here I use the date when I insert the data in my database.

I use the following code for inserting the data:

```
$sql="Insert into termocouple (no,tanggal,tanggal2,silo,sensor1,sensor2,sensor3,sensor4,sensor5,sensor6,sensor7,sensor8,sensor9,sensor10,sensor11,sensor12,ambien,average,deffiasi,status) 

Select no,tanggal,now(),silo,sensor1,sensor2,sensor3,sensor4,sensor5,sensor6,sensor7,sensor8,sensor9,sensor10,sensor11,sensor12,ambien,average,deffiasi,status from temp1";
```

Comment: "the code wont work" isn't an error message or problem statement. What's the issue? Have you checked if you're getting an error message back from the code? We can't see how you're actually executing this query. The code you've shown us simply declares a string and does nothing else. Also, what DBMS are you using (e.g. MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle?). Please tag it in the question.

Comment: i dont get any eror massage there.
i try to echo it but no value i got

Comment: `status` is a keyword, you cannot use it as a column name without putting backticks around it. Your query will certainly generate errors, try to output those first.

Comment: @MinervazMine usually the DB code library you are using will have a way to report errors explicitly. e.g. for mysqli, the mysqli_error() function is used. Just running the query usually only gets you a true or false ouput. You have to ask for the error, if the result of the query is false. Also, have you tried to run it in a SQL GUI program directly instead of via  PHP script? You'll definitely get a proper output form that. Seems like you need to learn some basic debugging skills.

Comment: @ADyson i have try to call mysqli_error() function there but i dont know why. it's no error massage i get

Comment: Since you don't actually show us any real code we cannot know what's wrong.

Comment: @MinervazMine Ok then like I said already. Try running the query directly into your SQL environment and see if it works or not.

Comment: @ADyson thx for your suggest. i found the eror there

Comment: No problem. So...what was the result of doing that?

Comment: just miss at. this
at the 1st db table `no` is foreign key. and for the 2nd db table `no` is a primary key. T_T its a basic method but im not check that TT_TT

Comment: "just miss at". "T_T". "TT_TT"?? No idea what you mean by any of that that. Is "no" an auto_increment field in your second table? If so then you can't explicitly insert a value into it. Again, what output do you get from running the query directly in a SQL environment?